# How to get only specific folder Item in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, onedrive, powershell-4.0

I have this script that use PnP module to delete a specific OneDrive folder but when every it do Get-PNPListItem, it getting the whole items from the List instead of specific folder that I provided so just wondering how should I fix that so that I don't have to wait too much time on getting the list item.

For simplify my question, when I run the script below, it getting all the Items from /Documents instead of a specific subfolder /PC-Offboard so the process of getting an items is really long since I have over 4 millions of item inside Documents.

So it'll be great if there is away to directly get an items from /PC-Offboard

```
#Config Variables
$SiteURL = "https://companyname-my.sharepoint.com/personal/d34_ks_com"
$ListName = "Documents"
$FolderServerRelativeURL = "Documents/PC-OFFBOARD/"

Try {
    #Connect to PnP Online
    Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -useWebLogin
    $List = Get-PnPList $ListName
        
    #Get All Items from Folder in Batch
    $global:counter = 0;
    $ListItems = Get-PnPListItem -List $ListName -PageSize 2000 -Fields ID, FileDirRef, FileRef -ScriptBlock `
    { Param($items) $global:counter += $items.Count; Write-Progress -PercentComplete ($global:Counter / ($List.ItemCount) * 100) -Activity `
            "Getting Items from Folder '$FolderServerRelativeURL'" -Status "Getting Items $global:Counter of $($List.ItemCount)"; }
 
    #Get List Items from the folder and Sort List Items based on Server Relative URL - Descending
    $ItemsFromFolder = $ListItems | Where { $_.FieldValues["FileDirRef"] -match $FolderServerRelativeURL } | Select-Object @{Name = "ServerRelativeURL"; Expression = { $_.FieldValues.FileRef } }, ID | Sort-Object -Descending -Property ServerRelativeURL
    Write-host "Total Number of Items Found in the Folder:"$ItemsFromFolder.count
          
    #Delete List Items in Batch
    $Batch = New-PnPBatch
    ForEach ($Item in $ItemsFromFolder) {
        Remove-PnPListItem -List $ListName -Identity $Item.ID -Recycle -Batch $Batch
        Write-host "Item Queued for deletion:"$Item.ServerRelativeURL
        Invoke-PnPBatch -Batch $Batch -Details
    }
    Invoke-PnPBatch -Batch $Batch -Details
 
}
Catch {
    write-host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)" -foregroundcolor Red
}
```

Comment: Can't you use the [-FolderServerRelativeUrl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnplistitem?view=sharepoint-ps#example-9) parameter, something like `Get-PnPListItem -List $ListName -FolderServerRelativeUrl "/Documents/PC-OFFBOARD"` ?

Comment: Hi Theo.. I just tried and I get this error " The 'query.FolderServerRelativeUrl' argument is invalid. " any idea?

Comment: I guess the relative url is incomplete. Mine was just a demo. Maybe it needs something like `"/sites/personal/d34_ks_com/Lists/Documents/PC-OFFBOARD"`. Only you should know the relative folder url..

Comment: Ok.. I have tried with that and now I'm getting different error. it'saying "The attempted operation is prohibited because it exceeds the list view threshold". I thought I already handle this threhold issue by adding -PageSize but not sure why I'm still getting that error.